# How to change the name of the column that I received after INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  * FROM train 
INNER JOIN station AS s1 ON train.id_station_departure = s1.id 
INNER JOIN station AS s2 ON train.id_station_arrive = s2.id
```

I want to get name1 and name2 ,not name and name. How i can make it?

Comment: You need to use keyword AS for it `SELECT name AS name1 FROM train`. You can also see this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: A good tip is NEVER use `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

You need  a column name alias ..  but in this case you can use select *  ..
If you need column name alias you must use  explicit column  name

```
SELECT  s1.name as name1, s2.name as name2
FROM train 
INNER JOIN station AS s1 ON train.id_station_departure = s1.id 
INNER JOIN station AS s2 ON train.id_station_arrive = s2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT  s1.name as name1, s2.name as name2`

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more information with your answer such as explaining why your solution is working.